# Number of downloads with awstats and WebClient class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webclient, user-agent, awstats

I'm using WebClient class to download a xml file where is written the latest version of my program to check for updates. I thought that I can see how many people are using my program by checking how many hits my update.xml gets with awstats. Me and my friend are testing the program for 2 days but awstats still says 0 hits.
Is it because I have no user-agent header? Still server logs (where awstats get it's data) should show that the file was downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading this file from outside of your LAN/intranet environment? I've run into an issue before where IIS reports that a file download was 0kb (and these don't show up in the awstats report) when downloaded locally, but shows up fine when downloaded from outside of the intranet environment.